# react lifecycle when using redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

in react, when the app start, it will run ComponentWill/DidMount, then for every this.setState(), the component will run componentWill/DidUpdate.

in redux, the store will subscribe a render function like this,

```
const store = createStore({Reducers})
function run(){
   ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("element"))
}
store.subscribe(run);
// then for every dispatch() action, store/reducer will run the render all over again
```

it seems to me that for every changes to store, redux will have to initialize component all over again.

1. Does this means that for every changes, the component will always run componentWill/DidMount(), it will never run componentWill/DidUpdate?
2. if no.1 is correct, does it make redux slower because it has to initialize the component for every update?

Comment: Rename your `run` function to `render` and this will fix your issue. Your app isn't being run, it's just being rendered. It's actually very efficient.

Comment: To be clear, React will actually be calling the update versions and not the mount vesper on each render (except the first).

Comment: I'd recommend you to use the [react-redux](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-redux) package as it makes it incredibly easy to connect your react components/containers to your redux store and manage state changes in your components.

I'd advise you to read this to get started: http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the answers to your questions:

> 1. Does this means that for every changes, the component will always run componentWill/DidMount(), it will never run componentWill/DidUpdate?

In my experience componentWill/DidMount is called just the first time, then yoy will have componentWill/DidUpdate, if the DOM structure doesn't change and only your component properties do.

> 2. if no.1 is correct, does it make redux slower because it has to initialize the component for every update?

Redux doesn't have performance issues because it uses React best practices and updates only the components that have their properties changed.

I reccomend two great resources to help you in your Redux / React journey:

- Redux tutorial has a [`Usage with React`](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html) section
- [Getting Started with Redux (30 free videos)](https://egghead.io/series/getting-started-with-redux)